# Pillow genera un array inconsistente con el tamaño de la imagen

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, pillow

Estoy pasando un screenshot tomado con `pillow` hacia un array con `numpy` pero por alguna razón el array no tiene el tamaño de la imagen ¿ Por que ocurre esto?

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageGrab import grab

import numpy

screenshot_pil = grab()
screenshot_numpy = numpy.array(screenshot_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')\
.reshape((screenshot_pil.size[1],screenshot_pil.size[0],3))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    .reshape((screenshot_pil.size[1],screenshot_pil.size[0],3))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4096000 into shape (800,1280,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa imagen tiene toda la pinta de ser **RGBA** y no **RGB**. Observa, que ocurre si se hacen los cálculos de los elementos del array (4096000 según el error) con canal Alpha y sin el:

> - ***RGBA:*** 800(alto) * 1280(ancho) * 4(canales) = **409600**0
> - ***RGB:***  800(alto) * 1280(ancho) * 3(canales) = 3072000

Teniendo esto en cuenta, tu captura es una imagen RGBA, por lo que probablemente estés realizando la captura en un sistema macOS. Si vemos la documentación oficial de Pillow:

> [`PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html#PIL.ImageGrab.PIL.ImageGrab.grab)
>
> Take a snapshot of the screen. The pixels inside the bounding box are returned as an “RGB” image on Windows or “RGBA” on OS X.

Basta entonces con que el array tenga las dimensiones adecuadas, esto es (800, 1280, 4) y no (800, 1280, 3):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageGrab import grab

import numpy

screenshot_pil = grab()
screenshot_numpy = numpy.array(screenshot_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')\
                        .reshape((screenshot_pil.size[1],screenshot_pil.size[0],4))
```

Comment: Efectivamente estaba trabajando en macOS gracias !